# iPad is offline, date set to 2030, user save entities, what now with timestamp based sync?

Tags: ios, database, core-data, synchronization, theory

The question is **merely theoreticaly**, really a rare use case, I'm just wondering about.

I have a client-server setup (CoreData, JSON, AFNetworking, etc.) where every account have multiply read-write users.

Therefore I timestamp every database entry with a `_lastModificationDate` to be able to sync / merge changes later.

So one of the users go offline, sets it's date to 2030 (with Set Automatically off). Save - so timestamp with 2030 - some entity, then go online.

20 years passed, user did not change a single thing. Still, every sync of this user will overwrite data in database until we pass 2030.

How should I get over this?

Comment: Is there any chance to get notified when iOS sets the date automatically? I could catch a delta there, and the problem should gone.

Comment: Another solution is "No internet connection. Please go online". :D

Answer (score 1):

You could either set a new field `modifiedOffline` (boolean), or, while he's offline, set `_lastModificationDate` +1 on each modification. However, in both situations, the updates from the server will/may overwrite the local ones, even if they're newer.

Another solution would be: after the user gets online, the app would refresh the `_lastModificationDate` to be at maximum current date (which I presume you fetch it from the server). This way, newer modifications will work normally.

Comment: Seems solution 1 simply kills offline modifications? Similar user experience if I'd never let user to modify stuff offline.

Comment: Solution 2 simply kills online modifications. Assuming the user go online after a year, it would overwrite server database with a year outdated data.

Comment: I think the solution is to get the delta of the local / server as soon as the user go online. The problem is that the iOS setting `Set Automatically` will sync the local date immediately as soon as the device go online.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response, and for 'voting back to 0' anyway.

Comment: Solution 1 only kills offline modifications if there are other modifications on the server. For second option, you may also ask the user to resolve 'conflicts' (for items that changed both on server and locally), by choosing what to update and not. The user may change the device's date several times, so I don't believe there's any perfect solution to this.

Comment: Exactly. Only perfect solution could be to be notified about date change. Maybe that is a question on it's own.

Comment: I got it. Schedule a local notification for every second of the next 100 years with a local timestamp the notification created. There you can get the deltas. :D Just kidding.

Answer (score 1):

The server database could have a sanity check. Modification dates in the future get set to the current date when first encountered. Maybe also dates pre-dating the iPhone ;-).

Comment: In this case future data would still considered as the latest. Though it still may be half a year outdated.

Comment: Have you tried this anyway in other apps? Twitter goes really fun. Emails from the future are also really lovely. They stick to the top for a long while in the inboxes. :D

Comment: Seemingly no one really cares about this. Me personally set the date really often to fool some realtime farming games. They don't address this issue either. So I can get all the goodies in minutes.

Comment: > "In this case future data would still considered as the latest." -- not for long. Same as if you use normal date. IMO, this solves the problem.